# Oracle JDK 16 Won't install

Tags: 20.04, java, jdk, oracle

This is running off a VM in Oracle Cloud

I tried fetching java 16 from

```
add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
apt install oracle-java16-installer
```

After executing the last command, I got this

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/16.0.2+7/d4a915d82b4c4fbb9bde534da945d746/jdk-16.0.2_linux-aarch64_bin.tar.gz?AuthParam=1634908993_119442deecff850f20dade187cd946 [following]
--2021-10-22 13:21:13--  https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/16.0.2+7/d4a915d82b4c4fbb9bde534da945d746/jdk-16.0.2_linux-aarch64_bin.tar.gz?AuthParam=1634908993_1                                                                                                    19442deecff850f20f0dade187cd946
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.66.96.32|:443... connected                                                                                                    .
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2021-10-22 13:21:14 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 16 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java16-installer (--configure):
 installed oracle-java16-installer package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java16-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@mc-server:/home/ubuntu#
```

I've tried many different instructions such as

```
apt-get install --reinstall packagename 
apt-get -f install
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq --dry-run
apt-get upgrade
dpkg --configure
```

None of them seemed to do anything effective.

I don't know what to do either

Comment: Did you read the output? It is quite clear why it was not installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ppa:linuxuprising/java` is a PPA created by somebody. It contains a package that tries to download Java from Oracle.

You сan see that Java couldn't be downloaded for some reason.

You can either download it manually and install according to Oracle manuals, or try to contact the PPA maintainer to get this issue fixed.

Comment: I suppose you mean, downloading the tar.gz file, loading it onto the server, and then installing it.

Comment: I mean exactly that.